# How to run a Makefile with a list of arguments from another file

Tags: linux, makefile, command-line-arguments, csh

I am using csh. 
Inside my makefile I have something like this:

```
run:
    program -switch "--alpha 3 --beta 4 --gamma 5"
```

My aim is to be able to set the arguments inside **-switch** when I run the makefile. I found different solutions on how to do it but in my case, the arguments of type alpha, beta and gamma are about 20-25 in number. Ideally I'd like to place them in a file like this:

> file: simple_script_run

```
--alpha 3 \
--beta  5 \
--gamma 5 \
--..etc
```

I'd rather have the arguments in separate lines for better readability. The file **simple_script_run** is located with other similar files each containing a configuration of the argument inside a directory **run_scripts**. The latter is located in the same path as my makefile. 
The aim is to be able to replace the list of arguments inside the makefile to something like:

```
program -switch "$(RUN_ARGS)"
```

It is mandatory that the list of arguments are contained with "". Now I'd like to run the makefile with a command similar to:

```
make run RUN_ARGS=$(< run_scripts/simple_script_run)
```

Obviously, this didn't work and I wonder why. Can you suggest a fix to my solution or a better idea? I'd be glad to hear from you.

Comment: I'm assuming that the problem with that attempt (since you didn't actually *say* what it was) was that you got a partial command and then a failure from the second line of the argument file being treated as a command in the recipe? make variables are expanded pre-shell so newlines expand literally. You need to transform the newlines into spaces when you read the file into the variable.

Comment: Changed the arguments file so there is no \n return and arguments are just separated by spaces. The shell outputs "Illegal variable name"

Comment: The shell outputs that when? Does quoting the `$(< ...)` argument help (I don't see how it should be necessary)? What does `set -x` report for that `make` line and the line in the recipe?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using c shell for tooling reasons. It works without problem under bash if the arguments are separated by space. But still doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: `csh` outside make or inside make? Because `csh` inside make is known, I believe, to be a non-starter. Outside make I wouldn't think it would matter assuming `make run RUN_ARGS=$(< ...)` is a valid `csh` command line (which it probably isn't in which case you'd need to do that differently but the idea should be fine). You never told me *what* was giving that argument error. Can you show the output from these attempts exactly?

Comment: @EtanReisner: both attempts 1) make run RUN_ARGS="$( < run_scripts/router_debug_run_one_line )" and attempt 2) make run RUN_ARGS=$( < run_scripts/router_debug_run_one_line ) have the same output: Illegal variable name. I am using csh outside the Makefile. I run the Makefile in csh environment. The problem disappears when I run the Makefile in a bash environment.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the `$(< ...)` construct is legal `csh` so it is probably complaining about the `<` in a variable name. If you **need** that exact command line then you can't use `csh` to run `make`. If you can use a different way to read the file then you can likely replace that with two (or more) lines that are valid for `csh` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

*Configuration file (backslashes not needed):*

```
--alpha 3
--beta  5
--gamma 5
```

*myprog:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "arg1=$1"
echo "arg2=$2"
```

*Makefile:*

```
# define the newline as a multi-line variable
define \n


endef

# Convert newlines to spaces in $(ARGS)
MK_ARGS := $(subst ${\n}, , $(ARGS))
# MK_ARGS := $(shell echo "$(ARGS)") # A more expensive way

all:
        @echo "MK_ARGS=$(MK_ARGS)"
        @bash myprog -switch "$(MK_ARGS)"
```

*Run result of `make ARGS="$(< config)"`:*

```
MK_ARGS=--alpha 3 --beta  5 --gamma 5
1=-switch
2=--alpha 3 --beta  5 --gamma 5
```

Comment: using program -switch "$(MK_ARGS)" in bash caused program to start without arguments " ". In csh, it outputs Illegal variable name

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot test it with `csh`. It seems to work with the `bash` shell.

Comment: I don't think you need the `sed` here. make will automatically convert newlines to spaces in the `$(shell)` function's output. See [The shell function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function).

Comment: I also don't know that I see the point of the `$(shell)` function here at all (other than to do the conversion in which case that's probably an expensive way to do it).

Comment: @Etan Reisner: I eventually managed to do the conversion with `subst` instead of `shell`.

Comment: Worked only when I migrated to bash and **re-inserted backslashes**. Error code: `/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
`/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: @Theo: make sure to have all files in unix format (run `dos2unix` on all)